# Connecting to a web server via HttpClient

Tags: android, rest, httpclient

I'm trying to connect to REST web server and I don't know what is going wrong. The code that connects is:

```
public List<Agenda> getAgenda(String dia) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "It is inside getAgenda()");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(Settings.getServiceUrl() + "/" + dia);
        Log.i(TAG, Settings.getServiceUrl() + "/" + dia);
        //the line above prints: http://192.168.0.100/odonto/agenda.php/2012-02-01
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(method);
        //return loadFromJSONArray(client.execute(method));
        Log.i(TAG, "Recebeu a response");
        return loadFromJSONArray(resp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Well, here is the thing: the line

```
Log.i(TAG, Settings.getServiceUrl() + "/" + dia);
```

prints on the debug window correctly. But the line:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Recebeu a response");
```

don't prints. So the problem is in line:

```
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(method);
```

But I really don't know how can this be wrong!! I've already tested the REST server with Firefox and it works just fine! The debug window with a filter to show just the tag System.err is in the link:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting permission denial error. Please add below permission in menifest file after application tag

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I added the line and worked just fine!! It have other error but the connection is now working. Thanks a lot...